# Understanding Phrasal Verbs

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I would like to ask a suggestion of a link, in which must contain Preposition's meaning applied to Phrasal Verbs, for instance:

A verb followed by a preposition "Up" can means: `complete, increase and move`, like: `finish up,turn on, stand up`.

To be more exactly what I want, would be a list where I could search meaning of preposition, or a word, like: "I would like to know what are the phrasal verbs that I can use to speak: `to arrive`, `to enter` etc..

I'm used to see phrasal verbs when I search a word definition, for example: [Get](http://thefreedictionary.com/get)

Is here I can see all phrasal verbs with "Get"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources. It might be moved to Meta?

Comment: Is it complex? has it many questions? Do you want I reformulate it?

Comment: There's an online [Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/) which may be what you're looking for. Ordinary dictionaries will give you the more common meanings of prepositions, and a thesaurus will give you synonyms for words, including p-verbs.

Comment: I was trying to find all meaning of preposition when applied with a verb, like "up" - increase, move, complete

Comment: To the extent that it can be done, dictionaries will give you that - look at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/up), for instance.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, you don't need to close this question, @anderson gives me too a great list, I was searching for that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have rules for meaning phrasal verbs.

The phrasal verbs: "make out"

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/make-up_2?q=make+up

There are more 8 meanings.

But if you want a big list phrasal verbs:

http://www.languageforlife.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Complete-PV-list.pdf